# how to persist keycloak in kubernetes custom themes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, keycloak

I have tried to persist the custom themes through `gcepersistentdisk` but when I enter the administration console it does not load anything, and checking the folder `/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes` is empty.

Also try creating a custom docker image (Dockerfile) by adding the following line to copy the custom themas.

`COPY /source-folder/login /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/login`

although in the folder `/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes` I can see the new login folder, when I access the administration console I cannot see the custom theme login.

I can only view the custom theme when I do it with the following kubernet commands:

1. `kubectl exec POD --namespace keycloak - mkdir /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/login`
2. `kubectl cp keycloak/login keycloak/POD:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/login`

With the previous commands if I can see the custom theme login in the administration console

I have tried using `gcePersistentDisk` as follows:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: keycloak
   ...
   volumeMounts:
     - mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes
       name: test-volume

  volumes:
    - name: test-volume
      gcePersistentDisk:
        pdName: pd-name
        fsType: ext4
```

In what way can I persist with custom themes when the pod restarts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand each theme should have own folder. It should be `themes/mytheme/login` instead of `themes/login`. For example, your local structure may look like:

```
Dockerfile
themes
|-mytheme
  |-account
  |-admin
  |-login
    |-resources 
      |-css
      |-img
    |-theme.properties
  |-welcome
```

Docker file may look like:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:8.0.1
ADD ./themes /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/
```

Build a docker image, run, then go to `Realm Settings -> Themes` and select your theme.

Answer (score 2):

Create a StorageClass and a PersistentVolumeClaim

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ssd-sc  # specify the storage class created below
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi

---

apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ssd-sc 
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
reclaimPolicy: Retain # Retain storage even if we delete PVC
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd # ssd
```

Create a Pod to use PersistentVolumeClaim

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: nfs-pvc
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

Comment: it didn't work for me when I try to enter the keycloak administration console it doesn't load

Comment: Have you mounted your volume using proper path ? What does `kubectl get pv,pvc` show ?